# Topdown approch for abcpdf doc object

Tags: abcpdf, topdown

the default (x,y) axis for doc object in ABCpdf starts at bottom-left corner. is there any way to make it top-left corner.?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to set the origin to top-left.

The simplest method is to set the Doc.TopDown property to true. Alternatively you can specify a transformation matrix.

More info on the Doc.TopDown property can be found here in the [documentation for ABCpdf...](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/2-properties/topdown.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to subtract all the y-position items by the height of the document (then get absolute value of that) - I found the height in my case was 840 (using doc.AddGrid();).

I noticed that TopDown stopped working after I'd upgraded from abcpdf v8 to v10 (for tls1.2 security reasons)

```
    private static void SetText(Doc doc, int xposn, int yposn, string text) {
        doc.Pos.X = xposn;
        doc.Pos.Y = Math.Abs(yposn - 840); //handle TopDown manually using after v10 upgrade
        doc.AddText(text);
    }
```

Note that I could not figure out the transformation matrix, but tried this - but didn't know the correct matrix to use:

```
        using (var doc = new Doc()) {
            doc.MediaBox.String = "A4"; // this sets the page to A4 (also removes scrollbar showing in the pdf LOL)
            //doc.TopDown = true;  //2022-02-16 jn appears to not work in v10
            var matrix = new Matrix(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
            doc.Transform.Matrix = matrix;
            
            doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
            doc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheEnabled = false;
            doc.HtmlOptions.UseNoCache = true;
            doc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheClear();
            ...
```